# JVM/Tomcat crashes when too many uploads occur in parallel (Heap Space)?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, grails, jvm

I have a Servlet application running on Tomcat 7. I set the following in setenv.sh

```
CATALINA_OPTS="
-server 
-Xms1G 
-Xmx5G
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8";
```

The server runs on Ubuntu 12.04LTS, has 6 Cores and 8GB of RAM. 
My application is a Grails/Spring/Java app where users can upload images. Sometime it occurs that 3-5 users start uploading images at the same time. In these situations my Tomcat crashes because of the following error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I know that I have to increase the Xmx parameter of my Tomcat to prevent this problem. But seriously what is wrong in my case?

1. Is there a best practice to handle file uploads like in my scenario?
2. Can I prevent this problem some how? I mean when 5GB are not enough for 3-5 parallel uploads how much resources do I need for hundreds of parallel uploads?
3. Is my app so bad or is it normal that file upload takes so much resources?

Note: The files that users upload are 2-8 MB.

This is how I do the upload in my view:

```
   <g:form method="post" action="save" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
   </g:form>
```

and in my Controller:

```
def file = request.getFile('image')
byte [] byteFile = file.getBytes()
```

In config/spring/resource.groovy I did:

```
beans = { 
  multipartResolver(org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver){

        // Max in memory 100kbytes
        maxInMemorySize=102400

    }

}
```

The uploaded file are images. They will be scaled and saved to disk.

The images will be saved as:

```
bytes [] currentImage = // some image in bytes ...
def newFile = new FileOutputStream(fullPath)
newFile.write(currentImage)
newFile.close()
```

Comment: How big are the files? try using jvisualvm to see what is grabbing all the memory.

Comment: Does your application hold the entire file contents in memory during upload? It is possible to stream a file upload, commons-fileupload supports this: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/streaming.html

Comment: @samlewis How is the file upload streaming done with Grails? Can you please formulate an answer?

Comment: 5GB of heap, and 3-5 users uploading 2-8MB files shouldn't be a problem even if you are not streaming. Maybe you should follow @BevynQ's suggestion of profiling with JVisualVM. If you want suggestions for improvements to your Grails App consider updating the question with your file upload code.

Comment: @samlewis I updated my question with my code for the upload. Any idea how I get the streaming working?

Answer (score 1):

Avoid [`MultipartFile.getBytes()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html#getBytes%28%29), use [`MultipartFile.getInputStream()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html#getInputStream%28%29) instead to avoid reading the entire file contents into memory.

So change your code to:

```
def file = request.getFile('image')
InputStream inputStream = file.inputStream
```

You haven't mentioned what you do with the uploaded file but make sure that throughout the layers of your application you pass `InputStream` and don't convert into a `byte[]` if you want to minimize heap usage.

Comment: Can you post how I should change my code to get the bytes of the file with your suggestion?

Comment: The uploaded file are images. They will be scaled and saved to disk. I updated my answer. How will you sage the image to disk as inputStream? Why is bytes[] bad?

Comment: The scaling is probably going to require the image to be read into memory, so streaming is probably not an option for you. I would go back to @BevynQ's suggestion of profiling with JVisualVM. byte[] is bad because it is the entire file contents in memory but for you this might be unavoidable.

Comment: So beside profiling what would you suggest to reduce memory usage when I have to scale the image? Is there some way to free the memory very fast after scaling?

Comment: Image processing uses a lot if memory so you could try to optimize. You could limit the number of images you scale concurrently e.g. with ThreadPoolExecutor. Personally I would require the user to upload an image of the correct size and just validate the width and height in your grails app using ImageIO.

Comment: If I load the file from disk would you prefer to use BufferedImage instead of byte [] ?